# SQL server database log file increasing enormously

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 5 SSIS jobs running in sql server job agent and some of them are pulling transactional data into our database over the interval of 4 hours frequently. The problem is log file of our database is growing rapidly which means in a day, it eats up 160GB of disk space. Since our requirement dont need In-point recovery, so I set the recovery model to **SIMPLE**, eventhough I set it to SIMPLE, the log data consumes more than 160GB in a day. Because of disk full, the scheduled jobs getting failed often.Temporarily I am doing **DETACH** approach to cleanup the log.

**FYI:** All the SSIS packages in the job is using **Transaction** on some tasks. for **eg.** Sequence Cointainer

I want a permanent solution to keep log file in a particular memory limit and as I said earlier I dont want my log data for future In-Point recovery, so no need to take log backup at all.

And one more problem is that in our database,the transactional table has 10 million records in it and some master tables have over 1000 records on them but our **mdf** file size is about 50 GB now.I dont believe that this 10 million records should make it to 50GB memory consumption.Whats the problem here?

Help me on these issues. Thanks in advance.

Comment: All your questions are answered if you do research but..... all dta going to the MDF files passes thorough the transaction log. It's just that SIMPLE recovery throws the log away afterwards and FULL waits for you to back it up first. If you wish you can shrink your MDF file but it's just going to grow again and take up valuable I.O doing it. Disks are cheap. Either spend a long expensive time optimising your processes or a short cheap time adding more disks.

Comment: Memory and disk are not the same thing.  A transaction log needs to span a a transaction.  If you have some big transactions then your transaction log will fill.  Simple - have smaller transactions.  And don't **SHOUT**.

Comment: @Blam... I never said it was stored in the MDF file...must be some misunderstanding there.

Comment: @Blam That was in response to the OP's last statement: "...... our mdf file size is about 50 GB now....".

Comment: @Blam There are two stated problems. One is the growth of the log file. The other is the size of the MDF file. My comment did not address either of these explicitly and that may have caused confusion.